# Why is Spring security Authentication returning a Null authentication object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

**I need to get the User object details for the currently signed in User so that I can get the customers assigned to the User** but I keep getting a null object when I printed to the console. I can sign in successfully with a generated token for the user type , but i keep getting null response when the logged in username is queried by Spring authentication.

**Controller**

```java
@RestController
public class CustomerController {
    
@Autowired
CustomerAccountService customerRepo;
        
@Autowired
UserAccountService  userRepo;

 @GetMapping(value="marketers/customers")
public List<Customer> getLlistByMarketerName()
{
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();  
User loggedInUser = userRepo.findByUserName(authentication.getName());
System.out.println("logged in user:"+ loggedInUser);
return customerRepo.findByMarketer(loggedInUser);
}
```

**The repository**

```
public interface CustomerAccountRepo extends JpaRepository <Customer, Long  > 

{
@Query("select customer from Customer customer join customer.marketer marketer where marketer = :marketer")
     List<Customer> findByMarketer(User marketer);
}
```

**UserDetails Service**

```
@Service
public class UserAccountService implements UserDetailsService {
    
    
@Autowired  
private UserAccountRepository userRepository;
        
private PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
       
public  UserAccountService (PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
         
       }
    
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);
if(user == null) {
throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
}
            
           // List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getUserRole()));
            
          return MyUserDetails.build(user);
}
```

**JWT Request filter**

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
private final UserAccountService userAccountService;
    
@Autowired
public JwtRequestFilter( @Lazy final UserAccountService userAccountService) {
this.userAccountService = userAccountService;
        
}
    
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

String username = null;
String jwtToken = null;
if (requestTokenHeader != null) {
jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
try {
username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
} catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
}
} 

if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
UserDetails userDetails = this.userAccountService.loadUserByUsername(username);
if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
String authorities = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
.collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println("Authorities granted : " + authorities);
usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
else {
 System.out.println("Not Valid Token");
        }

        }
chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

**The User entity**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String firstName ;
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="user_name", unique=true)
    private String userName;
    
    private String password;
    private String Gender; 
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Branch.class, 
     fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(name="branch_id") 
    private Branch branch;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date createdDate;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
    name = "users_roles", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<>();
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserStatus status;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="marketer",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=Customer.class)
    private List <Customer> customer;
```

This is **MyUserDetails class** that provides the username and password authentication details

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2456373662763511974L;

private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String email;
private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    
public MyUserDetails() {}
    
public MyUserDetails(Long id, String username, String email, String password,
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }
public static MyUserDetails build(User user) {
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getUserRole()
.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority
(role.getName()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
return new MyUserDetails(user.getId(),
user.getUserName(),
user.getEmail(),
user.getPassword(),
authorities);
        
}
```

**UPDATED:** Security config file . This is my first big project in Java , forgive my errors

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
  private UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
    
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      exposeDirectory("customer-photos", registry);
  }
    
    private void exposeDirectory(String dirName, ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      Path uploadDir = Paths.get(dirName);
      String uploadPath = uploadDir.toFile().getAbsolutePath();
       
      if (dirName.startsWith("../")) dirName = dirName.replace("../", "");
       
      registry.addResourceHandler("/" + dirName + "/**").addResourceLocations("file:/"+ uploadPath + "/");
  }

  @Autowired 
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
     
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
     @Bean
     public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) { 
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
     
     @Override
     @Bean
     public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
         return super.authenticationManagerBean();
     }

   @Override
     protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
     }

  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/auth/login", "/validate", "/**").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
      
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .exceptionHandling()
      .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
      
      .and()
      .formLogin().permitAll()
      
      .and()
      .sessionManagement()
      .maximumSessions(1)
      .and()
      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
      .and()
      .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login")
      .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
      http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: @xerx593 I just added the security config

Comment: Doesn't `antMatchers("/auth/login", "/validate", "/**").permitAll()` renders it unnecessary to authenticate to call `@GetMapping(value="marketers/customers")`?

Comment: @JoãoDias i thought the "/**" mean all other endpoints ?

Comment: Exactly, which means that basically all endpoints will require no authentication, hence you will have an empty `SecurityContext` on such calls.

Comment: @JoãoDias what should I do ? i removed the   "/**"  and changed to  "/marketers/customers" but getting same null

Comment: spring security has had JWT support since 2018, writing a custom JWTFilter is bad practice, writing any type of custom security is bad practice. Remove the JWTFilter and please implement JWTs in accordance according to the official spring security documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't want all your endpoints to not require authentication. In order to achieve it you will need to remove `/**` from your `permitAll()` in the security configuration as follows:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/auth/login", "/validate").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
    
  .anyRequest().authenticated()
  .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
  .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
  
  .and()
  .formLogin().permitAll()
  
  .and()
  .sessionManagement()
  .maximumSessions(1)
  .and()
  .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
  .and()
  .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login")
  .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
  http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Comment: I removed it and got error: "Unauthorized"

Comment: There you go. Now you need to authenticate to call such an endpoint so that you can have a non-empty `SecurityContext`.

Comment: .antMatcher("marketers/customers").authorizeRequests() ??

Comment: No. I will say it again. While calling the endpoint in Postman or whatever way you are doing it, you must provide an authentication method. From the code that seems to be a JWT Token that I am guessing you get after calling `/login` endpoint.

Comment: i logged in with post man and got a generated token , I added the token to the header and made a call to marketers/customers got and got a NullPointerException: null. I noticed that when I tried to logging with variable userName , it says bad credentials until i changed  to username but What I have on the User entity is userName. What could be wrong please ?

Comment: Where do you get the NullPointerException in your code? Knowing that would help.

Comment: When I make a Get request to marketers/customers endpoint  java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.bethsaida.org.controllers.CustomerController.getLlistByMarketerName(CustomerController.java:106)

Comment: Still, where exactly? What is null?

Comment: the response from User loggedInUser = userRepo.findByUserName(authentication.getName()); I believe

Comment: Then please confirm that is the case, also what does `authentication.getName()` returns and if `authentication` is `null` or not.

Comment: I added the token as authorization and after making a get request to the endpoint , what I got is  java.lang.StackOverflowError: null error. Forgive my disturbance, I am new to spring security

Comment: Then we need the code for `Customer` and other related entities. It seems to me that you have an infinite recursion in your model. Please also add the error that you are getting. Thanks.

Comment: I removed the toString method in the User and Branch entity and voila !! it is working now !!! thanks much I really appreciate your patience for me . You are a role model, I appreckiate you.